# How to find biggest node in given XML file?

Tags: .net, xml

i am new guy with XML. this is my XML file content:

```
<Root>
  <COMPANIES>
    <id>1</id>
    <CompanyName>apple</CompanyName>
    <CompanyInCome>450</CompanyInCome>
  </COMPANIES>
  <COMPANIES>
    <id>2</id>
    <CompanyName>MS</CompanyName>
    <CompanyInCome>458</CompanyInCome>
  </COMPANIES>
  <COMPANIES>
    <id>3</id>
    <CompanyName>Evga</CompanyName>
    <CompanyInCome>770</CompanyInCome>
  </COMPANIES>
  <COMPANIES>
    <id>4</id>
    <CompanyName>GF</CompanyName>
    <CompanyInCome>150</CompanyInCome>
  </COMPANIES>
</Root>
```

here i want to find biggest CompanyInCome node and to show on my webpage. How can i make it?

Comment: `InCome`? Probably should be `Income`. How are you reading the XML files? Also - what exactly have you tried? What _exactly_ are you having problems with? Please post your current code and explain the issues.

Comment: Biggest = highest value for `CompanyIncome`?? Is that what you're looking for??

Comment: You should probably rename `COMPANIES` into `Company`. And `ROOT` into `Companies`.

Comment: @user1104363: updated my response - to read the XML from disk, you need to use `.Load(filename)` instead of `.Parse()` .... please see the [MSDN tech library documentation on XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) for details!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Linq-to-XML, you could write something like:

```
string input = "....(your XML here).....";

XDocument xmltest = XDocument.Parse(input);

var result = xmltest
                .Descendants("COMPANIES")
                .OrderByDescending(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Element("CompanyInCome").Value))
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

This will return the `<COMPANIES>` node which has the highest numerical value in `<CompanyInCome>`.

**Update:** if you want to read your XML from an external file, use this line of code:

```
XDocument xmltest = XDocument.Load(@"E:\MyXML.xml");
```

The `.Parse()` method is used to parse an existing string of XML defined in your code - it does **NOT** read from disk.

Comment: i have got error message now. 
XDocument xmltest = XDocument.Parse(input);
XmlEception was unhandled by user code


yes i have put using System.Xml.Linq; but didnt work

Comment: @user1104363: Use `XDocument.Load(string)` to load data from file.

Answer (score 0):

The same using XPath (thus, works in .NET 2.0, for example):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path);

XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
XPathExpression sort = nav.Compile("Root/COMPANIES");
sort.AddSort("id", XmlSortOrder.Descending, XmlCaseOrder.None, "", XmlDataType.Number);

string max = nav.SelectSingleNode(sort).SelectSingleNode("id").Value;
```